# Remote Help HTTP GET Request Format String Denial Of Service Vulnerability

Tags: web-application, vulnerability

Is there any solution for "HTTP GET Request Format String Denial Of Service Vulnerability" in the Remote Help software?

I have referred many places but I could not find a solution.

Please refer the below links for more information.

[security space link](http://www.securityspace.com/smysecure/catid.html?id=1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.100548) 
 
[security focus link](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/38875/solution)

Comment: The last update on the software was on 2009. It is abandoned.

Comment: What do you mean "solution for"?? You need to give us more information, like what you are doing to trigger this error.

Comment: my application is being scanned for some security vulnerabilities, and on of them was this vulnerability. I didn't understood why this issue come up. By the word, "Solution for", I mean to ask how can i avoid this vulnerability. @MikeOunsworth

Answer (score 0):

Given that the vulnerable version is 0.0.7 and the [current version](http://remotehelp.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) is still 0.0.7 there is probably no fix, at least none from the vendor. Looks like abandoned software.